# Object has no attribute: 'add_internal'

Tags: python, attributes, pygame

I'm using Pygame to make a platformer game, and I'm trying to use a Class to draw the platforms in each level.

Here is the class for Level01:

```
class Level01(Level):
def __init__(self):
    Level.__init__(self)

    walls = [[300, 600, 210, 70],
             [500, 500, 210, 70]
             ]

    for item in walls:
        wall = Wall(item[0], item[1], item[2], item[3])
        self.wall_list.add(wall)
```

The final line in this code (self.wall_list.add(wall) seems to be where I'm having the error. It returns 'AttributeError: 'Wall' object has no attribute 'add_internal'.

And here is the class for Wall:

```
class Wall(object):
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    super().__init__()
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(green)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
```

Can someone help me out?

EDIT: Here's the code for Level class:

```
class Level(object):
wall_list = None
enemy_sprites = None

def __init__(self):
    self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
```

Comment: maybe  super(Wall, self).__init__() ?

Comment: @wolendranh: what would that do to help avoid the error with the `Wall` instance?

Comment: So what kind of object is `wall_list` here?

Comment: Yes, can you show us `wall_list` in class `Level`? 
Maybe use `append` instead of `add`?

Comment: Tried using `append` instead, did not work. Also added all the Level class code.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me `wall_list` is a [`Group`](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) (or any subclass of it), and you try to add a non-`Sprite` object to it (hint: `Group` calls `add_internal` on all sprites that get added).

If you want to use a `Group` with your `Wall` class, let `Wall` inherit from `Sprite`.

Answer (score 0):

add_internal() is a pygame.sprite.Sprite() function. In order to fix this error, copy this Wall class:

```
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(green)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
```